# Must I use "styles" or "style" in GetMap URL request?

Tags: geoserver

Im working on a GIS app that call WMS service from a Geoserver. The URL looks like this:

```
http://MY_SERVER_V_2_18_0/geoserver/wms/?styles=my_style&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=my_layer&...
```

As you can see I'm using plural `styles` on this request. This is NOT working when I use Geoserver v2.18.0, but when I use same request on Geoserver v2.17.2 I may use plural or singular `style` because both are accepted.

Because this problem came with a version upgrade, I need to know if I'll do right if I change my code to use singular `style` from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keywords in the `getMap` URL are defined by the [WMS specification](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wms/) and requires (and have always required) that `STYLES` be plural.

I don't have any instance running a service as old as 2.18 but it definitely works in 2.22.2 with `STYLES` (and `STYLE` as we are lenient in our parsing)

If you continue to have issues with `STYLES` in a recent GeoServer please raise a bug report.

Comment: Hi Ian. I bet a friend that you would be the first to answer. Can this be in any way related to the workspace scope? Can't check now if the style and the layer are both in same workspace.

Comment: Anyway.... your ```as old as``` motivated me to make an upgrade ASAP.